# What would cause a line break in nested tables but only within Outlook?

Tags: html-email

Here's what it's supposed to look like: 
[image]

Here's what it looks like in Outlook:

[image]

For some reason the "call us" table is being pushed to the next line below instead of staying in-line. I tried placing "white-space:nowrap" on tr's/td's and that didn't seem to solve my problem.

Below is the markup:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id="border-1" align="left" style="border-top: 4px solid #444; border-left: 4px solid #444;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p" width="50%"> <!--- Email Us Housing -->
                            <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" >
                                                  <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                           <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                               <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                   <a href="mailto:sales@bambams.com?Subject=Hello!" target="_top" style="text-decoration:none;"><img width="50" src="mail.png" alt="Send Us An Email"></a>
                                                               </td>
                                                           </tr>

                                                        </table> 
                                                      </td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table>

                                                <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
                                                    <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap; font-size:24px; color:#414042; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;" class="link-bump"  height="70"><a href="mailto:sales@bambams.com?Subject=Hello!" target="_top" style="color:#414042; text-decoration:none;">email us</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>  
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                        <table id="border-2" align="right" style="border-top: 4px solid #444; border-right: 4px solid #444;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p" width="50%">  <!--- call Us Housing -->
                           <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                               <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                     <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                         <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                           <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" >
                                              <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                  <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                       <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                           <td style=" white-space: nowrap; padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                                                               <a href="tel:703-372-1940" style="color:#414042; text-decoration:none;"><img width="50" src="call.png" alt="Call Us"></a>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>

                                                    </table>

                                                  </td> 
                                              </tr>


                                           </table>

                                           <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size:24px; color:#414042; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;" class="link-bump"  height="70"> <a href="tel:703-372-1940" style="color:#414042; text-decoration:none;">call us</a></td>
                                              </tr>


                                                </table>
                                       </td>

                                    </tr>

                                </table>

                               </td>
                           </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr><!---- top footer end --->  


            </table>
```

Comment: Image links are broken.  Can you readd so can review?
And is this happening in Windows Outlook clients? or IOS too?

Comment: I've uploaded links to the image. They should be working now. Happening in Windows Outlook

Answer (score 1):

You could try using out Outlook conditional code since this is solely an Outlook windows issue.  And then target it to whatever your dimensions are.

```
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640"> <tr><td align="center" valign="top" width="318">
                      <![endif]-->

                      Side 1 

                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td><td>
                      <![endif]-->

                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td></tr></table>
                      <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you, Richard. I'll try this out now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try what Richard has suggested by adding a ghost column

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td><![endif]-->
```

Or you can try doing something similar to below:

```html
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#444444" style="padding:4px;">
        
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    
                            <table id="border-1" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p" width="50%"> <!--- Email Us Housing -->
                            <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" >
                                                  <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                           <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                               <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;">
                                                                   <a href="mailto:sales@bambams.com?Subject=Hello!" target="_top" style="text-decoration:none;"><img width="50" src="mail.png" alt="Send Us An Email"></a>
                                                               </td>
                                                           </tr>

                                                        </table> 
                                                      </td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table>

                                                <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
                                                    <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap; font-size:24px; color:#414042; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;" class="link-bump"  height="70"><a href="mailto:sales@bambams.com?Subject=Hello!" target="_top" style="color:#414042; text-decoration:none;">email us</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>  
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                        <table id="border-2" align="right" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p" width="50%">  <!--- call Us Housing -->
                           <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                               <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                     <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                         <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                           <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" >
                                              <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                  <td style="white-space: nowrap;">

                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                       <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                                           <td style=" white-space: nowrap; padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                                                               <a href="tel:703-372-1940" style="color:#414042; text-decoration:none;"><img width="50" src="call.png" alt="Call Us"></a>
                                                           </td>
                                                       </tr>

                                                    </table>

                                                  </td> 
                                              </tr>


                                           </table>

                                           <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size:24px; color:#414042; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;" class="link-bump"  height="70"> <a href="tel:703-372-1940" style="color:#414042; text-decoration:none;">call us</a></td>
                                              </tr>


                                                </table>
                                       </td>

                                    </tr>

                                </table>

                               </td>
                           </tr>

                        </table>
                    
                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>



        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have added table with 4px padding around the two blocks you have and added CSS to the table which allows you to place tables side by side in outlook:

```
border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;
```

If this doesnt work you can decrease the width of the two columns to 49% and it should work properly.

**Note:** decrease the width if you are using my code above.

Hope the above helps.